# Automatic update for jar in maven

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, maven-3, drools

I am using Drools 6.4 and KieScanner for automatic updates in KieBase. I have setup remote repository and specified it in settings.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>useArtifactory</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>abc</id>
                    <url>My remote artifactory</url>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
    <activeProfiles>
        <activeProfile>useArtifactory</activeProfile>
    </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

When my application runs for the first time , It doesn't find jar in local maven so it downloads from remote repository. I have KieScanner which scans the maven repo in every 10 seconds. BUT the problem is if there any update in remote repo then the updates are not being downloaded on the fly. I am using fixed version 1.0 of the jar. What am I missing here ?

Comment: In  maven, fixed version of jar  are never redownloaded, because they are never expected to change. So either use SNAPSHOT VERSION and run mvn with -U (force  update dependencies for SNAPSHOT) , or eventually use version ranges. (discouraged, because it affects build reproductibility).

Answer (score 0):

If you want a version to be updated, you have to declare it as SNAPSHOT version, i.e. 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.

SNAPSHOT versions are replaced on a regular interval (standard is every 24 hours),
while release versions (like 1.0) are never updated. You can force the update of
a SNAPSHOT version by using the -u parameter in Maven.

SNAPSHOT versions are meant for development (so they can change), while release versions are considered to be stable so that everyone can depend on them without expecting change.